# Cannot stream video to peer when peer connects using simple-peer

Tags: node.js, socket.io, webrtc, p2p, simple-peer

I am using simple-peer for simplifying webrtc use and everything is working fine. But I am facing an issue where when the broadcaster starts the stream and a viewer joins the stream, no video is displayed to the viewer. But then if the broadcaster refreshes his page, video gets displayed on the viewer side.

**Broadcaster.js**

```
componentDidMount() {
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
        video: true,
        audio: true,
    })
        .then(stream => {
            // Display own video
            if("srcObject" in this.localVideo.current) {
                this.localVideo.current.srcObject = stream;
            }
            else {
                this.localVideo.current.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
            }

            // Stream video to attendees
            this.gotMedia(stream);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error(error);
        });
}

gotMedia = (stream) => {
    const broadcaster = new Peer({ initiator: true, stream: stream });

    broadcaster.on("signal", data => {
        this.socket.emit("signal", data);
    });

    this.socket.on("signal", data => {
        broadcaster.signal(data);
    });
};
```

**Viewer.js**

```
componentDidMount() {
    const attendee = new Peer();
    attendee.on("signal", data => {
        this.socket.emit("signal", data);
    });

    this.socket.on("signal", data => {
        attendee.signal(data);
    });

    // Get remote video stream and display it
    attendee.on("stream", stream => {
        if("srcObject" in this.remoteVideo.current) {
            this.remoteVideo.current.srcObject = stream;
        }
        else {
            this.remoteVideo.current.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
        }
    });
}
```

**Server**

```
// Handle socket connections
io.on("connection", socket => {
   socket.on("signal", (data) => {
      socket.broadcast.emit("signal", data);
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason why this happens is because the broadcaster sends a signal as soon as it is made. So the signal will only be sent once from the broadcaster, when the viewer connects later it won't get any signal.

To resolve this issue the viewer can be setup first and ask the broadcaster to create a new connection.

In this [github project](https://github.com/Dirvann/webrtc-video-conference-simple-peer/) you can see an example where more than 2 peers can get connected at the same time.

Here is an implementation:

**Broadcaster.js**

```
// this method is the same
componentDidMount() {
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
        video: true,
        audio: true,
    })
        .then(stream => {
            // Display own video
            if("srcObject" in this.localVideo.current) {
                this.localVideo.current.srcObject = stream;
            }
            else {
                this.localVideo.current.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
            }

            // Stream video to attendees
            this.gotMedia(stream);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error(error);
        });
}
// new way to handle
gotMedia = (stream) => {
    this.localStream = stream
    this.broadcaster = new Peer({ initiator: true, stream: this.localStream });
    this.broadcaster.on("signal", data => {
        this.socket.emit("signal", data);
    });
    // destroy current peerconnection and create a new one
    this.socket.on("startConnection", () => {
        if(this.broadcaster) this.broadcaster.destroy()
        this.broadcaster = new Peer({ initiator: true, stream: this.localStream });
        this.broadcaster.on("signal", data => {
            this.socket.emit("signal", data);
        });


    });
    this.socket.on("signal", data => {
         this.broadcaster.signal(data);
    });


};
```

**Viewer.js**

```
componentDidMount() {
    const attendee = new Peer();
    attendee.on("signal", data => {
        this.socket.emit("signal", data);
    });

    this.socket.on("signal", data => {
        attendee.signal(data);
    });

    // Get remote video stream and display it
    attendee.on("stream", stream => {
        if("srcObject" in this.remoteVideo.current) {
            this.remoteVideo.current.srcObject = stream;
        }
        else {
            this.remoteVideo.current.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
        }
    });

    // Ask broadcaster to start his connection
    this.socket.emit("startConnection")
}
```

**Server**

```
// Handle socket connections
io.on("connection", socket => {
   socket.on("startConnection", () => {
       socket.broadcast.emit("startConnection")
   });

   socket.on("signal", (data) => {
      socket.broadcast.emit("signal", data);
   });
});
```